# How to make an Android application act as a web server

Tags: android

I am making a Android application. I want to use Android device as a server. Client is a PC or other devices. Client can control server via a web browser.
How to make a web server on Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what is you exact requirement, but if you want to run light weight http server, you can take look at `nanoHTTPD`, its very light weight and easy to integrate in any app as it is just a single java file.

https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Answer (score 0):

Try this for server instal https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd
Of if essence of your purpose is only control your application use sockets 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

in your case browser will be a client